# How to remove top-level bullet points in Sphinx html docs

Tags: python-3.x, python-sphinx

I would like to remove the bullet points of the top-level headers in the htmls generated by sphinx (from a python project, rtd theme). I have been attempting to do this from within a custom css file, but was unsuccessful. In the css file I tried:

```
.toctree-l1  li {
   list-style: none;
}
```

and variations involving

```
div, h1, li
```

I manage to do some other formatting customization via that same css file, with,

```
@import 'theme';
.toctree-l1 > a {
   font-weight: bold;
   font-size: 1.2em;
}
```

which suggests paths and options in the conf.py file are set up correctly.

[Edited first snippet to reflect comment.]

Comment: Have you used CSS inspector to check whether your CSS style is applied or not?

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa: yes, the bolding and fontsize have been applied but not the list-style.

Comment: List style applies to `li` elements, not `a` elements

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa: ```.toctree-l1 li {list-style: none;}``` doesn't work either.

Comment: Try UL. Use your CSS inspector to find out the element you need to modify.